# Kotlin buildSrc failing on Gradle 4.10 due to missing dependency

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When upgrading to Gradle 4.10, I faced the following error when attempting to compile:

```
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':buildSrc:kotlinCompilerPluginClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:1.2.60.
     Searched in the following locations: file:/Users/<user-name>/.gradle/caches/4.10/embedded-kotlin-repo-1.2.60-2/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable/1.2.60/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.2.60.jar
     Required by:
         project :buildSrc
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-sam-with-receiver:1.2.60.
     Required by:
         project :buildSrc
```

Note that I was using `buildSrc` as part of my Gradle compilation process.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is due to a breaking change in [Kotlin DSL 1.0](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/releases/tag/v1.0-RC3):

> The kotlin-dsl plugin now requires a repository to be declared
>
> With Kotlin 1.2.60, the Kotlin Gradle Plugin driving the kotlin compiler requires extra dependencies that aren't required by Gradle Kotlin DSL scripts alone and aren't embedded into Gradle.
>
> This can be fixed by adding a repository that contains Kotlin compiler dependencies on the project where the kotlin-dsl plugin is applied: `repositories { jcenter() }`

Answer (score 13):

build.gradle.kts should contain

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
// Required since Gradle 4.10+.
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```